# Efficient runtime representation of setter/getter functions

Tags: compiler-construction, interpreter, vm-implementation

For a class declaration like (using a dynamically typed language I am develop):

```
class Foo
{
    var bar
    {
       get { return bar; }
       set(value) { bar = value; }
    }
}
```

User can the write something like:

```
var f = New Foo();
f.bar = 20;
var n = f.bar;
```

The compiler then will convert f.bar = 20 to a setter call and n = f.bar in a getter call. What could be an efficient runtime representation of the setter/getter functions inside the Foo class?

Should the compiler decide to use to setter ONLY based on the fact that f.bar is used in an assignment expression?

Comment: Are you interpreting your own language in C, as it seems so from your other questions and the tags in your question. Please update the question accordingly.

Comment: this might be C#, it doesn't quite look like C++.

Comment: I modified the question, it is a dynamically typed language I am developing.

Comment: I am developing a dynamically typed language and a virtual machine, my question about how the compiler should decide about when to use the setter method and what could be an efficient runtime representation of the setter/getter methods is a generic question not related to the language used in the examples.

Comment: Did you really mean to write dynamically *scoped* in the question? Note that this is **not the same thing** as a dynamically *typed* language!

Comment: Sorry my fault, I meant dynamically typed (original post fixed).

Comment: If this is dynamically typed then how can you tell the type of `f` at compile time (which is required to determine the correct getter/setter)?

Comment: But the question is about how to accomplish this efficiently at *runtime*. It is clearly not possible at compile time.